# Strange Salesforce.com SOQL relationship syntax

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, soql

I'm looking at an SOQL query that may either be hideously out of date or using some facet of their magical **field__r.foreign_table** join syntax, the code contains a reference to

**USER_JOBS__R**

where nothing like that currently exists as a field on the current objects there are however tables called both **USER** and **JOBS** of which JOBS contains a lookup on USER.

Has anyone ever seen this as part of the SOQL syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, take a look at [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm) for Relationship Queries, it'll have everything you need.

Because the table `USER_JOBS__R` is plural and ends in `__R` it's likely going to parent to children query.  `USER_JOBS__R` is called the "Child Relationship Name" and is created when ever a lookup field is created.  If you find the lookup that defines the child to parent relationship you can confirm this by looking at the field definition (note that the `__R` will not be present as this is only needed with the API).  In general if you have a lookup, say from an applicant to a job, whose name is `JOB__C`, the child relationship name will be a pluralized and `__C` replaced with `__R` to give you `JOB__R`.  This is only the default, you can choose whatever you want for the child relationship name.  Knowing this you could do the following query to give you all applicants along with each job:

```
[select id, (select id from APPLICANTS__R) from JOB__C]
```

For your scenario I would assume there is some "Job" object that has a lookup to the User object, probably `USER__C`, that has a child relationship name of `USER_JOBS__R`.

Answer (score 0):

The one that you are referring is generally called relationship fields (the fields ending in “__r”)

Answer (score 0):

This is the syntax for querying fields in a lookup (parent-child) relationship.